# Dynamical setting of drop down value from child window in parent form not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript

I have written below javascript code to set the dropdown value from child window in the parent page. This code is working fine in all the Browsers except for IE. I am using IE 11.

```
for(i=0;i<coverNamelist.length;i++){
 option = new Option(coverNamelist[i],i);                    
 eval("window.opener.document.parentform.coverdropdown.options[i] = option");
}
```

for testing other alternatives , i have also tried below code just to add a new entry in dropdown but no luck in IE :

```
  var sel = window.opener.document.getElementById("coverdropdown");
  var opt = sel.options;
  opt[opt.length] = new Option("Select","0")
```

kindly help to resolve this issue.

Comment: IE is obsolete, and not supported by MS any more.

Comment: Drop `eval`, it's not needed here. Also, using element ids in the script directly is not recommended (those references are too easy to override with JS variables), use appropriate DOM traversing method instead. What comes to the issue itself, IE11 doesn't support Option constructor. Create the new option element using `document.createElement` method, and add the newly-created option to the select element using `appendChild` method (by standard, writeable options collection is optional, and is maybe not supported in all browsers).

Comment: I have written below code as suggested :

Comment: var option =   document.createElement("option");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Select");
        option.appendChild(t);

Comment: But i am not able to figure out how to set this to the parent page dropdown ? could you please suggest ??